# Freeform Next Fieldtype - If form selected

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace-freeform-next

I have a Freeform Next fieldtype so that the client can choose from one of the forms that have been built to include in any of the pages. In my template, I need to be able to check if they selected a form or not to display something along with the form, however, using an if statement (see below) isn't working and is still outputting the rest of the HTML in the condition even when no form is selected.

```
{if page_form}
<div class="about-body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="pdt95 pdb95">
                    {page_form}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/if}
```

I still end up getting everything inside that conditional minus the form. If a form exists, it does display correctly. I've also tried:

```
{if page_form != ""}
```

But no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I just tested this on my end and it appears to work correctly as expected. Which versions of EE and Freeform Next are you using?

Comment: We're using the latest version of EE & FreeForm Next (3.5.11 & 1.0.6)

Comment: Latest version of Freeform Next is 1.2.0